# Show a mat-spinner when data that are already fetched and present are changed or overwritten

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, onchange

My app shows a spinner on page load while data isn't yet retrieved from a request

```
<!-- working as intended -->
<div *ngIf="!data && !error">
  <mat-label class="center">Loading...</mat-label>
  <mat-spinner [diameter]="200"></mat-spinner>
</div>
```

but I also want to show a spinner when the already fetched data changes but it's not working.
I've tried with a boolean `*ngIf="isLoading"` (initial `isLoading = false`) and changing it to `true` at the start of the value change trigger (**button press**) and setting it back to `false` when the data is overriden,

```
<!-- here I want to show the spinner until the data.text is overriden -->
<div *ngIf="data && !error"> 
  <p class="text">{{ data.text }}</p>
  <div *ngIf="isLoading && !error">
    <mat-label class="center">Loading...</mat-label>
    <mat-spinner [diameter]="200"></mat-spinner>
  </div>
</div>

<button mat-raised-button class="btn" color="primary" (click)="changeData()>
  Change
</button>
```

but it does not work.

My .ts component (relevant only):

```
dataChanged: any;
isLoading = false;

getData(){ //this is called on ngOnInit, so I get the mentioned spinner while waiting for the initial data
  this.myService.getData(this.params.data).pipe(take(1)).subscribe({
    error: (e) => {
      this.error = e;
    next: (saData) => {
      this.data = saData.text;
    },
  });
}

changeData() { //called on button press
    this.isLoading = true; //my manual approach as mentioned
  this.myService.getData(this.params.data).pipe(take(1)).subscribe({
    error: (e) => {
      this.error = e;
      this.isLoading = false;
    },
    next: (saData) => {
      this.dataChanged = saData.text;
      this.data[0].text = this.dataChanged[0].text
      this.isLoading = false; //my manual approach as mentioned
    }
  }
}
```

I've found some information about making a service and component but it seems a bit overkill to me.
Any ideas on how to achieve this?